# NameError: name 'ReleaseDeal' is not defined in Django

Tags: python, list, function

i'm getting NameError:  for the following code...

```
d = [('1','as'),('2','sd')]
for i in d:
    RD = ReleaseDeal(int(i[0]))
    print(RD)

def ReleaseDeal(a):
    RD = '''<ReleaseDeal><DealReleaseReference>R'''+ no +'''</DealReleaseReference><Deal><DealTerms><CommercialModelType>AsPerContract</CommercialModelType>
        <Usage><UseType UserDefinedValue="GoogleMusicBasic">UserDefined</UseType> <UseType UserDefinedValue="SscSnmLocker">UserDefined</UseType>
        <UseType UserDefinedValue="GoogleMusicSubscription">UserDefined</UseType></Usage><TerritoryCode>Worldwide</TerritoryCode><PriceInformation>
        <PriceType Namespace="DPID:"">13</PriceType></PriceInformation><ValidityPeriod><StartDate>2018-10-04</StartDate></ValidityPeriod>
        </DealTerms></Deal></ReleaseDeal>'''
    return RD
```

i'm getting following errors...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 3, in <module>
  RD = ReleaseDeal(int(i[0]))
NameError: name 'ReleaseDeal' is not defined
```

please help me on this , Thanks in advance..

Comment: you need to define the function before you use it. Just move the definition of `ReleaseDeal` further up the script

Comment: @Robin Zigmond - Thank you very much Mr. Robin Zigmond...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got several errors:

1. Define something before you reference to it
2. The parameter does not apply to the used one in ReleaseDeal
3. Concatenation of int to string fails.

   ```
   def ReleaseDeal(no): # this was a, is has to be no and string
       RD = '''<ReleaseDeal><DealReleaseReference>R'''+ no +'''</DealReleaseReference><Deal><DealTerms><CommercialModelType>AsPerContract</CommercialModelType>
       <Usage><UseType UserDefinedValue="GoogleMusicBasic">UserDefined</UseType> <UseType UserDefinedValue="SscSnmLocker">UserDefined</UseType>
       <UseType UserDefinedValue="GoogleMusicSubscription">UserDefined</UseType></Usage><TerritoryCode>Worldwide</TerritoryCode><PriceInformation>
       <PriceType Namespace="DPID:"">13</PriceType></PriceInformation><ValidityPeriod><StartDate>2018-10-04</StartDate></ValidityPeriod>
       </DealTerms></Deal></ReleaseDeal>'''
       return RD

   d = [('1','as'),('2','sd')]
   for i in d:
       RD = ReleaseDeal(i[0])
       print(RD)
   ```

Maybe type hints are useful for you ;-) https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ClassVar Then you can say something like

```
ReleaseDeal(no: str) -> str:
```

So you want to get no of type string and return string.